# webpack css background image not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I have created the html boilerplate with webpack. The problem which i'm facing is, if i call image in scss like "background: url('/img/img.png');" it doesn't taking. Here, I've attached the webpack file and folder structure. I used to try with "url-loader", this is also not working. Please help someone to fix this issue, because i have been tried so long to get this done but still can't able to find the solution.

This is my folder structure,

```
Project
     |   
     +-- html
     |  |  
     |  +-- css
     |  +-- img
     |  +-- js
     |  +-- index.html
     |    
     +-- src
     |  |  
     |  +-- js
     |  +-- scss
```

**webpack file**

```
'use strict';
let webpack = require('webpack');
let path = require('path');
let nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
let exp = []; // multiple exports array

// Exports configs for each language
let configs = [
    {
        name: 'min',
        entry: './src/index.js',
        scssRule: {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: [{
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: { minimize: true },
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: { minimize: true },
                },
                ],
                fallback: "style-loader"
            }),
        }
    }
];

// Generate exports module for each config
for (let c of configs) {
    var e = {
        context: __dirname,
        watch: true,
        entry: c.entry,
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'html/'),
            //pathinfo: true,
            filename: "js/app.js"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "jshint-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true },
                    }],
                    fallback: "style-loader"
                }),
            },
            c.scssRule,
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '../[path].[ext]',
                    publicPath: '../',
                    emitFile: false
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '../[path].[ext]',
                    publicPath: '../',
                    emitFile: false
                },
            }
            ]
        },
        // Use the plugin to specify the resulting filename (and add needed behavior to the compiler)
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'css/app.css'
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compressor: { warnings: false }
            })
        ]
    }
    exp.push(e);
}

module.exports = exp;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @hunzaboy i'm get 404 error. If i did like "background: url('../img/img.png');" getting can't resolve modules issue

Comment: I think you need to add images loader. More here https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-understanding-webpack/

Comment: Why don't you use absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file-loader` options have to be changed to work as desired. You want `file-loader` to emit the file to the output directory, otherwise you would need to copy the images manually instead of having it automated, therefore you should not set `emitFile: false`.

Your output directory is `html/` and with the current name `../[path].[ext]` you would put the files outside of the output directory (in your projects root directory), but that is not desirable since you should be able to deploy the output directory as is, without having to add anything outside of it (the build directory can be seen as the root of the server). Also `[path]` does not include the filename, but only the path to it. Assuming you want all the images in `html/img/` you could use `name: 'img/[name].[ext]'`.

The public path is used as a prefix in every path, which can be useful when serving it from a different base URL, for example if you served your app on `/my-app/` you would also need to request `/my-app/img/name.png` and not `/img/name.png` (public path takes care of this). See also [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath).

The two `file-loader` rules (fonts and images) could look like this:

```
{
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
},
{
    test:  /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        name: 'img/[name].[ext]',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
},
```